# Random Forest Analysis Giving NaNs

Tags: dataframe, nan, random-forest

I have a df that is all numeric values. Columns 1:1028 are the predictors and columns 1029:1033 are the responses. Here is a subset of this:

```
      PhHAL9G636300 PhHAL9G639600 PhHAL9G640000 PhHAL9G642000 PhHAL9G643800 PhHAL9G645300 PhHAL9G646100 PhHAL9G646600 PhHALJ003900     Biomass      Growth    WaterLoss
PENW3      5.365778    2.98025485      5.495861   4.405202465     2.9113147     2.5418600    2.09767062    2.52296664    1.9087030  0.46125981 -13.4226665  -0.37320470
PENW1      3.490321    4.64568874      3.717329   3.604487984     2.1293068     2.2661013   -1.47617955   -0.83020824   -1.4564567  4.61259811 -14.4985291  -1.41470618
CERD2      4.602228    1.83881344      4.474194   2.395140203     3.7523682    -0.2886215   -0.73070022    2.79344405   -0.7981627 -0.76634289   5.5581189  15.96563076
COCW2      4.614825    1.59769640      5.498260   0.006269791     1.9118368     4.2591423    3.73962184    2.53800230    2.5671915 -0.13178852 -25.7182390  -0.07377302
PENW2      2.874244    3.33668026      2.686314   3.640362110     3.3344128     1.5625493   -1.92483779    0.85800308   -1.8455277 -0.09584619 -15.5743917  -0.99376599
NIGD3      2.534445    1.86024236      3.028953   3.531425944     4.2376438     2.0732650   -0.46514048    0.79555084   -0.5451820  1.05436439  12.0221867  21.04783002
PEND2      5.362056    2.64328649      4.464727   3.452061385     3.8409665    -0.5227258   -0.06950176    2.05314895   -1.5741809  0.68405104   4.6766551  11.99731270
CERD3      6.379754    3.02126477      5.958883   2.617817128     3.2571087     0.6389388   -1.54158346    2.70402517   -1.5102857 -0.98235901   4.4562891  15.74806130
PEND3      5.530008    3.49150186      4.664897   4.122665811     3.4805644     1.6611925    1.00556471    2.13871970   -0.5366320  0.42174575   3.2075488  12.88432662
NIGW3      4.183288    5.26329612      5.928775   8.194201254     1.4188970     3.3488663   -0.24100014    1.17649150   -0.3305682  0.29951936   1.1783257   1.30187685
SORW2      6.893395    3.84929409      7.853042   0.700629044     1.2822700     3.7429352    2.73703304    3.38057924    2.5338634  0.02995194 -12.5004986  -5.77946530
BISD3      7.044496    2.75794859      3.816874   2.703812532     2.6916801     2.3260304    3.37232732    2.31685090    1.7024061 -1.02864818  -0.6121276  14.66858209
COCD2      5.393332    3.05175638      5.822644   2.200587922     2.2212163     2.4246024    3.13408898    2.07709126    2.1863062 -0.10286482  -2.4485105   7.86349310
BISW2      2.174211    2.62450842      5.128353   4.037738498     1.3183220     0.9764650    0.53499762    1.02802526    0.4124477  1.55750066 -25.8719336 -13.89189391
SORD3      6.154951    2.22626768      4.676438   0.489662530     1.1602737     1.6238320    3.90773303    3.34912476    3.7395865  0.11315130   0.2693362  17.67178436
COCW3      4.341137    4.05631371      5.292476   2.505723413     0.4784145     0.1552958    2.35139206    2.34302308    1.9836908 -1.03034659 -25.2571550  -1.06753902
CERW1      4.980878    0.91666130      2.190792   1.724122567     3.0002243    -0.9078029   -1.30732267    1.90047369   -1.3084019 -0.11381736 -10.3487734  -0.48603403
NIGW1      4.310666    5.24869379      6.482000   6.341412520     2.6579484     3.7324397   -0.69538644    1.39456781   -0.7667490 -0.07787503   1.9467990  -2.35639710
SORD2      3.439050    1.01743984      3.608031   1.984325521     0.9697594     1.9438491    2.75019240    3.59450372    3.0152745 -0.14915399   1.8118978  19.30355526
BISW3      4.995399    3.02559441      5.391413   0.707718031    -0.0867396     2.1041361    3.57258520    2.88651590    2.2532781  1.48561601 -26.3330176 -12.63775254
SORD1      4.867184    3.58269882      5.082423   0.847579020     1.1842905     3.2943452    3.54584508    2.26684212    3.2791237 -1.80013432  -3.0361530  18.53648347
NIGD2      3.433412    1.38880580      5.344590   6.113465129     1.3389915     0.9967764    0.55527371    1.04742251    0.4318620  1.16237244  10.5530804  20.06039943
SORW3      6.832991    3.48434777      7.954499  -0.373941722     0.9673997     3.8959556    2.87342668    3.53076025    2.5194703  1.12619278  -7.8896590  -6.45557334
PEND1      4.536131    1.98241616      2.469180   2.938093546     4.6266296    -0.3003059   -1.62573524    1.53755316   -1.5869045  0.49889437   3.3544594  12.90013295
CERW3      3.947328    1.97539246      4.499408   1.135578151     2.1385166    -0.2011640   -0.65101772   -0.06185877   -0.7272633 -0.04193271  -7.1211857  -1.98319240
NIGD1      1.517705   -0.02588437      2.040182   4.303738855     3.0117854    -0.9594330   -1.35627738    0.18988023   -1.3514038  0.88463744   8.0555996  20.38861318
COCW1      4.705918    2.51742179      4.476741   0.975394641     1.2854224     3.7611179    3.28623937    2.48855442    3.5451750  0.60502910 -26.9477962   0.97206804
BISD2      4.838736    3.99032517      7.239421   2.461942761     2.4587895     2.0971745    3.19578030    2.09829508    1.4836582 -1.10579679  -0.9059489  14.44078502
```

I am following the IPMRF package manual (pg 7):

```
#IMP based on CIT-RF (party package)
library(randomForestSRC)
library(party)
mtcars.new <- mtcars
ntree<-500
da<-mtcars.new[,3:10]
mc.cf <- cforest(carb+ mpg+ cyl ~., data = mtcars.new,
control = cforest_unbiased(mtry = 8, ntree = 500))
#IPM case-wise computing with OOB with party
pupf<-ipmparty(mc.cf ,da,ntree)
#global IPM
pua<-apply(pupf,2,mean)
pua
```

But I am switching mtcars for my dataset. However, when I run mine, I get all NaNs in the output and I can not figure out what is wrong with my code. So far I've checked if everything is numeric, if it's a limit in predictors (tried 10 rather than 1028), changed mtcars to have negative values to check that since mine has negative values, but none of these seem to be the problem. Granted, please double check me just in case. Here is my code that I am running with my dataset:

```
phallii.cf = cforest(Biomass + Growth + WaterLoss ~., data= RFTrainData, control=cforest_unbiased(mtry=33, ntree=1000)) #mtry = p/3 

da = RFTrainData[,1:1028] #predictor variables only

ntree=1000

phallii.ipm = ipmparty(phallii.cf, da, ntree)
```

If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Play small ball baseball instead of going for the home run. By that I mean that you should try to output the initial input and intermediate results before going for the final output results. Doing so should shed light on the cause of your problem.

Comment: @JohnH - valid point! Do you have any recommendations looking at the cforest object to flag any issues? This would be an intermediate step. I have been looking at plotting individual trees within the forest object but if there is a more efficient way that would be great.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the syntax background to give you specifics. My suggestions is just SOP for debugging software in general. Go upstream in the processing to validate the data being manipulated. Eventually, you should find the cause of your problem. Start with the input data, just echo back what you are trying to read in and go from there.